# Online link of CSS is not working

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas, css3pie

I was creating email template but unfortunately online link is css is not working so that I am unable to add original fonts to the text. Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>HTML</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Sunil Nehra">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ezinetechnologies.com/design/2014/travis/font/stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body style="font-family: 'futuramedium', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<div style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:12.8000001907349px; margin:0 auto;">
  <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img style="max-width:600px" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/-zbqc6a6aIbzcjC5vujbx_4Lj4ACf-igKmWSxoCTqQlisyiSwszRMuKf1hYL4WQXRPFiOGGRpLQQEJ-fyDSvAuIGrYb1mh64UXF_4qQZWQoDNBgZ83dEp0ZtdKjqnrdsetP2Egco-JGxw0bhwVOG3HzUK63Bh5x1SmAs1Dc=s0-d-e1-ft#https://gallery.mailchimp.com/5c25c42347b2d807c72dbc5d2/images/3c8a1a6d-205c-441c-a28e-a95803aee4d1.jpg" alt="Ready For Take Off?" class="CToWUd a6T" tabindex="0">
          <div class="a6S" dir="ltr" style="opacity: 0.01; left: 552px; top: 224px;">
          <div aria-label="Download attachment " tabindex="0" role="button" class="T-I J-J5-Ji aQv T-I-ax7 L3 a5q" id=":18v" data-tooltip-class="a1V" data-tooltip="Download">
            <div class="aSK J-J5-Ji aYr"></div>
          </div>
          <div dir="ltr">
            <div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="center" height="66" colspan="3"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" height="40"><em> <img width="219" height="32" style="float:left" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/e6nLB5X9PQuNeBW1uJFqicqZrQ3ss0Fc9tqVIYOTKHdOi9lPxhxRilCE5FS9h5O95wuJy24ddDCOWkJuHNW7GpnWctCuQO6VtT2EBIe1MbVsUNbsnYizhWdQWQcO7JZuG6icSd48VFMpvXUql6ri_e8ZbOT_-25oZfAMqfs=s0-d-e1-ft#https://gallery.mailchimp.com/5c25c42347b2d807c72dbc5d2/images/822ba1e7-e5da-44d4-be18-bd4dac733568.gif" alt="Red Bull College" class="CToWUd"></em><span style="color:#94969c;">
                  <p style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:0px; display:inline-block;"> 13TH - 17TH OF APRIL 2015 <br>
                    RED BULL HQ COLLEGE</p>
                  <span><span><span data-term="goog_1244661817" class="aBn" tabindex="0"></span></span></span></span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top"><p style="color:rgb(147,149,152);text-align:justify; font-family: 'futuramedium', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 9px;line-height:12px;"><font>Hello!&nbsp;<br>
                    <br>
                    We are pleased to welcome you as a participant of Red Bull College, which will be held at our Headquarters in Austria, April 2015.&nbsp;<br>
                    <br>
                    The objective of the College is to introduce you to the world of Red Bull; we will cover a range of topics from Brand Marketing, Sports, Events and Culture Marketing, Red Bull Media House, Product &amp; Production, Consumer Products and On &amp; Off Premise.<br>
                    <br>
                    The College will also allow you to experience some of the famous Red Bull landmarks such as the Red Bull Hangar-7 and the Flying Bulls!&nbsp;<br>
                    </font></p></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table></td>
        <td width="180" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top"><p style="color:rgb(147,149,152);text-align:justify; font-family: 'futuramedium', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 9px;line-height:12px;"><font><br>
                    <br>
                    For organization purposes we would ask you to please arrange your own flights to arrive in Salzburg on&nbsp;<span><span><span data-term="goog_1244661818" class="aBn" tabindex="0"><span class="aQJ">Monday 13th April 2015</span></span></span></span>&nbsp;(no later than 1600) and your departure on&nbsp;<span><span><span data-term="goog_1244661819" class="aBn" tabindex="0"><span class="aQJ">Friday 17th April 2015</span></span></span></span>&nbsp;in the morning.&nbsp;<br>
                    <br>
                    Please work with your local travel agent for any visa requirements for entry into the EU.&nbsp;<br>
                    <br>
                    If you require an invitation letter, we need a scanned copy of your passport. The visa process can take up to 1 month so please contact us immediately so we can support with this.</font></p></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table></td>
        <td width="180" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top"><p style="font-family: 'futuramedium', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-align:justify;font-size: 9px;line-height:12px;"><font ><br>
                    <br>
                    <font color="#939598">The HQ team will handle accommodation and most&nbsp;travel arrangement, therefore we will require your travel details as soon as&nbsp;possible - Please RSVP by 6th March 2014.</font><br>
                    <br>
                    <font color="#939598">With such a large group of participants, we would greatly appreciate prompt response which you can do on the official Red Bull College Collaboration group by following the link below.&nbsp;</font><span style="color:rgb(147,149,152)"><br>
                    <br>
                    We hope to see you there!<br>
                    <br>
                    <strong>International Brand Team</strong></span></font></p></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" colspan="3"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="right"><em><a target="_blank" style="border:0px" href="https://collaboration.redbull.com/groups/training-group-red-bull-college"> <img width="228" height="52" style="border:0px" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/YZCB9mHmbnOGGIkbxV9YVrtTyOuWCJTKOvkjFWhiw0L4XKWSfvLKWOqZ8ga2jRtbqjWSzBjlCcAdPN4jzNqYb_oBb9keCILUh3LS9h3Tz77RjspJ90pXajR1APSXzpQJg9o=s0-d-e1-ft#http://gallery.mailchimp.com/5c25c42347b2d807c72dbc5d2/images/click_here.gif" alt="Click Here to Take Off" class="CToWUd"></a></em></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <style>
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'futuramedium';
    src: url('http://ezinetechnologies.com/design/2014/travis/font/futurabt-medium-opentype-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://ezinetechnologies.com/design/2014/travis/font/futurabt-medium-opentype-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://ezinetechnologies.com/design/2014/travis/font/futurabt-medium-opentype-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://ezinetechnologies.com/design/2014/travis/font/futurabt-medium-opentype-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://ezinetechnologies.com/design/2014/travis/font/futurabt-medium-opentype-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://ezinetechnologies.com/design/2014/travis/font/futurabt-medium-opentype-webfont.svg#futuramedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
  </style>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Downvoting a question has nothing to do with knowing or not the answer. Anyway, I think you're gonna have a bad time if you want to use font-face in an html e-mail

Comment: Note: The web fonts only work in the apple mail...other email clients don´t accept the web fonts - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/webfonts/

Comment: @Jonas so, can we at least know _why_ you downvoted? (if you did so)

Comment: @JeremyThille: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not @ OP: The most useful information you're going to get about why your question was downvoted can be found in the tooltip on the downvote button and the [help]. *(No, I didn't downvote it. But I'm not supposed to tell you that...)*

Comment: I did not downvote this, so I don't know, sorry

Comment: Okay so, that's "Eat this, while I'm going away anonymously"? Not really constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom font will not work in an email across all clients! you'll have to stick to the basic font families I'm afraid.

Comment: And even those might get ignored.

Comment: Indeed, I normally stick to Arial, Tahoma or Century Gothic